# Troubles about Kivy with Socket connection

Tags: python, sockets, kivy

I have been learning python and its kivy library recently, and I want to make a **kivy interface that can display socket communication** (The information sent by the server can be displayed on the Label of the kivy interface), but it is always wrong. Because the program **reported no error**, I tried a lot to fix these files, however, I could't figure it out.

I would be very grateful if you could answer my questions。

### This is my main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from client import *


class AnchorLayoutWidget(AnchorLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.mys = Mysocket()

    def show_data(self, nap):
        try:
            self.ids.recv.text = self.mys.recv
        except Exception as e:
            print('e')


class AnchorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AnchorLayoutWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    AnchorApp().run()
```

---

### This is my client.py

```
import socket

class Mysocket:

    def __init__(self):
        sk = socket.socket()
        sk.connect(('127.0.0.1', 1029))

        if True:
            print('connect successfully!')

        while True:
            self.ret = sk.recv(1024)
            self.recv = self.ret.decode('utf-8')
```

### This is my server.py

```
import socket

sk = socket.socket()

sk.bind(('127.0.0.1', 1029))

sk.listen()
conn, addr = sk.accept()

while True:
    info = input('<<')
    conn.send(bytes(info, encoding='utf-8'))
```

### This is the anchor.kv

The "hello" and "world" are just something I was testing，both have nothing to do with my main program.

```
 # coding:utf-8
<AnchorLayoutWidget>:
    padding: 20
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        Button:
            text: "hello"
            background_color: 0,1,1,1
            size_hint: .5,.5
            font_size: 40

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        Button:
            text: "world"
            background_color: 0,1,1,1
            size_hint: .5,.5
            font_size: 40

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'left'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Label:
            id: 'recv'
            halign: 'left'
            valign: 'middle'
            italic: True
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: (0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos: self.pos
                    size: self.size
            text: "123"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            font_size: 30
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'right'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        Label:
            id:ID_input
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba:(.1,.1,.1,.1)
            text:"123"
            size_hint: 0.5,0.5
            font_size: 30
```

Comment: On first glance I notice that your code `self.ids.recv.text = self.mys.recv` is not calling the `recv()` method of `socket`. Try adding `(1024)`: `self.ids.recv.text = self.mys.recv(1024)`.

Comment: Also, you have two `while True:` loops in your posted code. If these are on the same `App` and not on different threads, only one will be running.

Comment: @John Anderson:Dear Mr. Anderson, thanks for pointing out my problems, I am trying to fix them in your proposal. If there’s any progress，I‘ll post my code again. Thanks again for your help!